# Hide Activity Indicator Does Not Work

Tags: objective-c, swift

The activity indicator starts, but does not stop when the hide function is called. I've tried putting the hide function in various places, and it still does not hide.

Hide activity indicator: `Q0ViewController().hideActivityIndicator(self.view)`

I'm using the swift utility function found here:
https://github.com/erangaeb/dev-notes/blob/master/swift/ViewControllerUtils.swift

**Start activity indicator**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Q0ViewController().showActivityIndicator(self.view)
    self.locationManager.delegate = self //location manager start
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

**Hide activity indicator after query:**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
            //return
        }
        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            currentLoc = manager.location
            currentLocGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(location:currentLoc)
            var query = PFQuery(className:"test10000")
            query.whereKey("RestaurantLoc", nearGeoPoint:currentLocGeoPoint, withinMiles:100) //filter by miles
            query.limit = 1000 //limit number of results
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if objects != nil {
                    unfilteredRestaurantArray = objects
                    originalUnfilteredArray = objects
                    println(objects)
                } else {
                    println("error: \(error)")
                }
            Q0ViewController().hideActivityIndicator(self.view) //HIDE
            }
        } else {
            println("error: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

It is not an issue with the main queue as `dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ()->() in` does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what Joshua suggested, just replaced:

```
Q0ViewController().showActivityIndicator(self.view)
and
Q0ViewController().hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
```

To:

```
self.showActivityIndicator(self.view)
and
self.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're creating a new instance of the "Q0ViewController" each time.

Instead I would suggest retaining the initial instance as a property on your class:

```
// As a variable on the class instance
let myViewController = Q0ViewController()

// Initially show the activity indicator
self.myViewController.showActivityIndicator(self.view)

// Hide the activity indicator
self.myViewController.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but i seem to be getting an error with the variable on the class instance [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/E93Zt2r.png)

Comment: looks like you were very close. just had to change the `Q0ViewController().` to `self.`